# Refurbish propane range top grates w/ KBS Coating XTC (rated to 1500 deg. F.) Suitable for a propane range grates? Exposed to direct flame?

Tags: painting

Whirlpool propane gas range and oven. Black color stove top burner grates, Cast Iron.

Comment: why are you asking here? ... ask the manufacturer

Answer (score 1):

Propane can reach temps well over 2000f as far as a stove top burner you might be right on the edge as the mixture is not as well mixed as a “turbo torch” that uses propane and air . We used the same coating in light blue for a quad header and it held up ok until we sold it. So it may be worth a try , I have never put a thermocouple in the flame.